# Creating a dictionary with values identical to keys from another dictionary

Tags: python

Perhaps having a dictionary with values identical to their keys is a sign of poor programming. In either case, what is the best or most elegant way to create a dictionary with values identical to the keys, where the keys are taken from another dictionary? In other words, I want to achieve `dict2` here without explicitly filling it:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'value 1', 'b' : 'value 2', 'c' : 'value 3'}
dict2 = {'a' : 'a', 'b' : 'b', 'c' : 'c'}
```

where also

```
topDict[1] = dict1
topDict[2] = dict2
```

The keys `1` and `2` in the actual application are language codes, and the language represented by `2` is the "native" language, and so the key for the nested dictionary in the case of  `dict2` is not meant to be translated, but rather used as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
dict2 = {k: k for k in dict1}
```

This simply loops over all the keys of `dict1` and echos that key as the value as well for each key-value pair.

Comment: In older versions of python, you may have to resort to the dict() function:  dict([(k,k) for k in dict1])

Comment: @MayurPatel: you can omit the `[..]` there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're need a dictionary. Take a look at [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
s = set(dict1.keys())
```

Comment: The dictionaries are translation maps; look up the original and get a translation. Using a dictionary for the 'original language' makes translation code much simpler as it doesn't have to special-case that.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters, I just thought that may be OP doesn't know about sets and trying to emulate it with dictionary

Comment: @HaiVu: no, the *rest* of the data structure is all dictionaries. Using *one* set over-complicates the code.

Comment: I am not familiar with sets, but per Martijn Pieters' comments, I don't think they are what I am looking for (though I'll look more into them).